# Jquery clone(true) - but I have changed element classname

Tags: jquery

---

### Clone(true)

When I clicked on `Clone` text of the sentence `Clone, how are you?` below 
**but I have changed the class from b to a** then

```
output is coming:
    B Handler for .click() called.
    A Handler for .click() called.
```

I have `changed the classname` from b to a then why it is not coming only `A Handler for .click() called.` alert? `Why it is happening?`

---

### Clone()

When I clicked on `Clone` text of this sentence `Clone, how are you?` below then

```
output is coming:
A Handler for .click() called.
```

Html

```
<h3>Click on the bold 'Clone' text to see the issue</h3>
<br/>

<!-- We will focus on the below HTML markup -->
<b class='b'>Clone</b>
<p>, how are you?</p>
```

JS

```
$('b.b').click(function () {
    alert('B Handler for .click() called.');
});

/*$('b.a').click(function () {
    alert('A Handler for .click() called.');
});*/

$(document).on('click','b.a',function (){
    alert('A Handler for .click() called.');
});

$('b.b').clone(true).removeClass('b').addClass('a').prependTo('p');
```

Here is the [Working Demo on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nits5457/y1rrajwo/).

Answer (score 1):

Because you have used `clone(true)`, it will copy the attached event handlers and data to the new object. Once the handler is attached any changes made in the selector will not affect added handlers.

When you use delegated event handlers, the selector is evaluated lazily when the event has occurred, so it could react to any changes done to the selector properties

Comment: Thanks! Please can you give me an example of  "delegated event handlers" related with above example. It will help me in understanding.

Comment: @Nits `$(document).on('click','b.a',function (){})` is a delegated event handler, in this case the click handler is added to the document object, so when ever a click happens within the document jQuery will try to see whether the click originated within a `b.a` element if so the click handler will be called